How to apply "AsemblyLinearVelocity" from scripts onto "hit.Parent"
Here is the code:
script.Parent.Activation.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    local part = Instance.new("Part")
    part.Size = Vector3.new(1,1,1)
    part.Transparency = 0
    part.CanCollide = false
    
    hitboxActivated = true
    script.Parent.Handle.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        --NPC
        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Torso") and hitboxActivated == true then
            local torsoPart = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Torso")
            hitSFX.Parent = torsoPart
            hitSFX.Volume = 2
            screamSFX.Parent = torsoPart
            hitSFX:Play()
            screamSFX:Play()
            torsoPart.AssemblyLinearVelocity = script.Parent.Handle.CFrame.LookVector * 1500
            hitboxActivated = false
        end
        --PLAYER
        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Torso") and hitboxActivated == true then
            local torsoPart = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
            hitSFX.Parent = torsoPart
            hitSFX.Volume = 2
            screamSFX.Parent = torsoPart
            hitSFX:Play()
            screamSFX:Play()
            
            part.Position = torsoPart.Position
            part.AssemblyLinearVelocity = script.Parent.Handle.CFrame.LookVector * 100
            part.Parent = torsoPart
            
            local weld = Instance.new("WeldConstraint")
            weld.Part0 = part
            weld.Part1 = torsoPart
            
            hitboxActivated = false
        end
    end)
    wait(3)
    hitboxActivated = false
end)

Whenever I test the tool in game, it doesn't apply the force onto the hit player. It just does
AssemblyLinearVelocity = 0,0,-0

I have tried multiple ways to try and fix, but still no luck. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?
PS: It only works on NPCs, not players.

Why do you have the same if statement twice? And why are you working on part instead of torsoPart in the second if statement?

This is so I can weld the part to the Torso and give the part the AssemblyLinearVelocity, so it can fling the player. I doubt it will work though, any ideas?
